# Multiple form upload: get each file name separately in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, multiple-file-upload

I want to upload some files. I use codeigniter:

`Html:`

```
<input type="file" name="file1" />
<input type="file" name="file2" />
```

`php:`

```
$config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
$path = $config['upload_path'];
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
$config['encrypt_name'] = 'TRUE';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value['tmp_name']) && $value['size'] > 0) {
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($key)) {
               // some errors
            } else {
                // Code After Files Upload Success GOES HERE
                $data_name = $this->upload->data();
                echo $data_name['file_name'];
            }
        }
    }
```

When I want to `echo` file name, I get `1.jpg` and `2.jpg`. But I want to have them separately and insert them into database.

How can I do this? Thank you :)

Comment: Wiil you please post the output here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the the value from `$data_name['file_name']` into an array and after your foreach loop do a insert_batch.

something like:

```
$filename_arr = array();
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value['tmp_name']) && $value['size'] > 0) {
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($key)) {
               // some errors
            } else {
                // Code After Files Upload Success GOES HERE
                $data_name = $this->upload->data();
                $filename_arr[] = $data_name['file_name'];
            }
        }
    }

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $filename_arr);
```

Comment: I want to insert them in one string and separate them by `,` How can I do this? Thanks :)

Comment: Use implode() on the $filename_arr - array - like $x = implode(',', $filename_arr);